# The error is not caught with try block in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

The error will be thrown because wrong CSV row accessed, but the error won't be catched by try block. Why, and how to catch it?

```
import parsecsv

# Prepare a file
let content = """One,Two,Three,Four
1,2,3,4
10,20,30,40
100,200,300,400
"""
writeFile("temp.csv", content)

var p: CsvParser
p.open("temp.csv")
p.readHeaderRow()
while p.readRow():
  try:
    echo p.rowEntry("wrong") # <= Error here
  except:
    echo "error"
p.close()
```

The error

```
$ nim c -r run.nim 
Traceback (most recent call last)
/alex/projects/run.nim(33) run
SIGSEGV: Illegal storage access. (Attempt to read from nil?)
Error: execution of an external program failed: '/alex/projects/run '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you import the [segfaults](https://nim-lang.org/docs/segfaults.html) module, this type of error can be caught. I assume it isn't imported by default for performance reasons.

Why it's an error in the first place is less clear. Strings used to be nilable in Nim, so I assume at the time `parsecsv.rowEntry` was written, it would return `nil`, which you could then check for. This isn't possible anymore, so the proc should probably be updated to raise an error. I'll look into it.

Comment: This has been fixed, and should be part of Nim 1.4. `parsecsv.rowEntry` will now raise a `KeyError` if the specified key doesn't exist. https://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/parsecsv.html#rowEntry%2CCsvParser%2Cstring

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://nim-lang.org/docs/parsecsv.html#rowEntry%2CCsvParser%2Cstring):

```
## `parser.rowEntry("NotExistEntry")` causes SIGSEGV fault.
```

Your headers are stored in `p.headers` so you can "catch" the error with code written like this:

```
var p: CsvParser
p.open("temp.csv")
p.readHeaderRow()
while p.readRow():
  if "wrong" in p.headers:
    echo p.rowEntry("wrong")
  else:
    echo "error"
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it would be possible to still catch it? A situation in Nim with errors in general, how to write reliable programs and being able to catch all possible errors.